# I have defined expected results as global. But cypress only takes the first declared expected result for every assertion on JS alert

Tags: cypress

I have declared expected results(globally). I have to get actual from the simple JS alert. I am using cypress. while Adding customers when js alert hits its is fine, assertion passes. but when i open the account using open account tab. first declared  expected value is taken for the second assertion also.

i have globally declared expected

let expected

first assertion

```
            // confirming the success message from the js simple alert
            cy.on('window:alert', (acutal) => {
                expected = "Customer added successfully with customer id"
                expect(acutal).to.contain(expected)
            })
```

second assertion

```
            // confirming the success message from the js simple alert
            cy.on('window:alert', (acutal) => {
                expected = "Account created successfully with account Number"
                expect(acutal).to.contain(expected)
            })
```

But the problem is <---- expected = "Customer added successfully with customer id" ---> this expected is taken for the both assertion first one passes and second one files. I have tried every way but it fails.

```
///    <reference types="cypress"/>
import AddCustomer from "../PageObjects/addCustomerPage"
import landingpage from "../PageObjects/landingpage"
import ManagerPage from "../PageObjects/managerPage"
import OpenAccount from "../PageObjects/openAccountPage"

describe("Simple banking app", () => {

    let expected
    
    it("login as mananger -> add Custormer", () => {
        // page objects
        let lp = new landingpage()
        let mp = new ManagerPage()
        let addCustomerPage = new AddCustomer()
        let openAccountPage = new OpenAccount()

        //url
        cy.visit("https://www.globalsqa.com/angularJs-protractor/BankingProject/#/login")
        // login as manager
        lp.clickManagerLogin()
        // assert the page is for manager
        cy.url().should('include', 'manager')
        // click add customer
        mp.addCustomerButton()
        // assert the page is for adding customer
        cy.url().should('include', "manager/addCust")
        // enter data and click add customer button

        cy.fixture('customerDatas').then((customers) => {
            for (let customer of customers) {
                addCustomerPage.setFirstName(customer.firstname)
                addCustomerPage.setLastName(customer.lastname)
                addCustomerPage.setPincode(customer.pincode)
                addCustomerPage.clickAddCustomerButton()
                addCustomerPage.clearAll()
            }

            // confirming the success message from the js simple alert
            cy.on('window:alert', (acutal) => {
                expected = "Customer added successfully with customer id"
                expect(acutal).to.contain(expected)
            })

        })

        //go to open account page and assertiong of the page
        mp.openAccountButton()
        cy.url().should('contain', "/manager/openAccount")

        cy.fixture('customerDatas').then((customers) => {
            for (let customer of customers) {
                openAccountPage.selectFromCustomerDropdown(customer.firstname + " " + customer.lastname)
                openAccountPage.selectFromCurrencyDropdown("Rupee")
                openAccountPage.clickProcessButton()
            }
            
            // confirming the success message from the js simple alert
            cy.on('window:alert', (acutal) => {
                expected = "Account created successfully with account Number"
                expect(acutal).to.contain(expected)
            })
        })

        // verify customer is added in the list
        mp.customersButton()
        cy.fixture('customerDatas').then((customers) => {
            for (let customer of customers) {
                //verify customer is added in the list
                cy.get('tbody>tr>td').should('contain', customer.firstname)
            }
        })

    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `cy.on()` to `cy.once()` for each of the different `expected` strings.

Each of the listeners should turn off after the first time it is used when you use `cy.once()`, and allow the next one to capture the alert.